# How to use Search constraints REST API specification in Websphere Portal 8.5

Tags: search, constraints, websphere-portal

Recently I needed to use the search REST API for a project, I found the documentation and do step by step as follows:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYJ99_8.5.0/Search-Rest-api/Search.html

But to search constraints, I use it according to the documentation, the results returned are incorrect.

Do I need to configure where in the portal to use search constraints ? I am using `IBM WebSphere Portal 9 Build Level: 20161208-1058 2016-12-08 12:09 CF13`. Thank you!

I use the link URL search REST API, as followed:

```
http://localhost:10039/wps/contenthandler/searchfeed/search?constraint=
{"type":"field", "id":"authoringtemplate", "values":["bidv-template-demo"]}
&queryLang=en
&locale=en
&resultLang=e
n&query=developer
&scope=com.ibm.lotus.search.ALL_SOURCES
&start=0
&results=10
```

Comment: Reformatted in a more conventional way

Comment: You should provide more details on the errors you face in your question.

Comment: No have errors,  but the results returned are incorrect with value of constraints

Comment: have you tried something else besides authoringtemplate to see if that might work, and if it is just having problems on that one?